# Debugging AJAX + Jquery Webpage - dynamic loading of contents seems not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, web

I've found a possible bug while i was using jquery and Ajax function on my new website, or more probably some big bug on my code that is driving me crazy.

Here's the website url for further documentation,
http://phpschool.altervista.org/is/

The problem occurs when i call the function loadXML to load some contents using ajax this way:

```
      $("#menubar .button").live("click",function () {

           $("#aj_load").fadeOut("slow", function()
           {                
              loadXML('archive/'+$(this).attr("id")+'.html');
           });

      });

// #menubar .button is the identifier for the menu buttons.
// #aj_load is the div that contains ajax contents when requested.
```

So the meaning of this code, should be

```
Fade out the contenitor aj_load,
Load Contents using ajax,
Show out the contenitor with contents,
```

But, When i do so, ajax request report error 404 or 12000, and the script stops running.

If you try on the website to click the about button for example, you should see it's working correctly, because i've modified the code in order to remove the fadeOut function from the contenitor:

```
        $("#menubar .button").live("click",function () {

            loadXML('archive/'+$(this).attr("id")+'.html');
        });
```

Why a fade function should interfere anyway with ajax requests?
I can't explain this.

loadXML contains .load() function from jquery, you can see it on the website.

Thanks very much,

EDIT:

```
function loadXML(xmlURL)
{
resetStyles();

$("#aj_load").load(xmlURL+" #content0"+cur_seq, function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") 
    {
        var msg = "Pagina Non Trovata: ";
        $("#aj_load").html('<br/><br/><br/><h3 style="text-align:center">'+msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText+'</h3>');
    }
    else
    {
        num_seq = $("#aj_content").text();
        if(num_seq !="0")
        {
            $("#less").off("click").on("click", function()
            { 
                $("#aj_load").fadeOut("slow",function()
                {
                    slideUP(num_seq);
                    loadNEXT(xmlURL,"prev");
                });
            });
            $("#more").off("click").on("click", function()
            {
                $("#aj_load").fadeOut("slow",function() 
                {
                    slideDW(num_seq);
                    loadNEXT(xmlURL,"next");
                });

            }).fadeIn("slow");
        }

    }
}).delay(300).fadeIn("slow",function(){inAnimation();});
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `loadXML`

Comment: Aside from possible problems on your javascript, I checked the live site and it's really returning 404s for most pages. First of all, you must make sure the pages exist and are accessible by a normal request (test by entering the URL in the browser address bar directly). You 'about', 'formazione' and 'contatti' pages do exist, the others do not.

Comment: Sorry i've forgot to say, that the pages that actually are online are Formazione, About and Contatti. So for the rest of them is actually right that the script reports 404. Thanks

Comment: It's not the `fadeOut` that causes the problem, it can't be. Are you sure it causes a 404?! This might be related: when your site loads, it's giving the following error: `_prep_animat is not defined`.

Comment: I know it's a nonsense, but the problem actually happens just when i call the fadeOut to the contenitor first. in every other cases everything works just fine. _prep_animat is not defined because to prevent loading of the function prep_animat during debug, i've added a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you use `$(this)` to get the button ID you're actually getting the ID of the element you're fading.  Try this instead...

```
$("#menubar .button").live("click",function () {
    var buttonID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#aj_load").fadeOut("slow", function()
    {                
        loadXML('archive/' + buttonID + '.html');
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Just modified your script on-the-fly and the above works fine.  It looks nice as well.  Think I might pinch that idea for when I rebuild my site ;)

Comment: Yeah, That's right! it was driving me crazy for real! i think i'm going to get another cup of coffee. Thanks very much!

Comment: It's always fun when there's something so obvious that you just can't see!  Glad to help mate :)